# Magento 2.3.3 After completing the order as a guest user unable to create a new account

Tags: checkout, customer-account, magento2.3.3

Recently after upgrading our site to Magento 2.3.3 Version, the guest user can't create an account after successful checkout.

I am getting the below log messages, can someone help me on this.

```
main.DEBUG: URI '/checkout/account/delegateCreate/'' cannot be accessed with POST method 
   (Magento\Checkout\Controller\Account\DelegateCreate)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this file in your custom template it might be the problem:

```
app/design/frontend/YourCompany/yourtemplate/Magento_Checkout/web/template/registration.html
```

You may need to compare and replace the contents with that in the magento distribution:

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/registration.html
```

for example;

```
<div>
<!-- ko if: isFormVisible -->
<p data-bind="i18n: 'You can track your order status by creating an account.'"></p>
<p><span data-bind="i18n: 'Email Address'"></span>: <span data-bind="text: getEmailAddress()"></span></p>
<a class="action primary" data-bind="attr: { href: getUrl() }">
    <span class="btn btn-default" data-bind="i18n: 'Create an Account'" />
</a>
<!--/ko-->
```

Comment: Thanks for your support, we are using a custom template file, this functionality is changed in the latest version upgrade. After updating our custom template file it is working now